# Copy-Item error and how to catch access is denied

Tags: powershell, profile, copy-item

I have a script that backs up User Profiles Documents.

The code is:

```
$sourceFolder = "C:\Users\username\Documents"
$backupFolder = "C:\temp\Backup\profilefolders\username\Documents"
Copy-Item -Path $sourceFolder -Destination $backupFolder -Recurse -Force
```

However,  When the cop hits a folder My Music, My Pictures, My Videos I am getting understandably an error Access to the path 'C:\Users\username\Documents\My Music' is denied.
Since the folders are only shortcuts to folders in the users root folder.

I can add -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue to have the errors ignored.

But I want to show an error but not like this in red:

```
Copy-Item : Access to the path 'C:\Users\username\Documents\My Music' is denied.
At C:\Temp\scripts\folderbackups.ps1:60 char:13
+             Copy-Item -Path $sourceFolder -Destination $backupFolder  ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (My Music:DirectoryInfo) [Copy-Item], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CopyDirectoryInfoItemUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

Is there a quick way to just have an error message that just shows with background in red:

"Error: access to C:\Users\username\Documents\My Music denied and not backed up."

Obviously use a variable that picks up the location.

Cheers

Comment: Investigate exception handling using try/catch/finally.

Comment: Can't have try catch scenario as this would potentially fail the entire copy of the directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use [redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection) `2>&1` to merge the non-terminating error that occur into the success [output stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Output_Streams).
- Given that [`Copy-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item) normally produces *no (success) output*, you can therefore assume that any objects emitted are *errors*, specifically instances of type [`System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord).
- You can process these objects in a [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) script block, craft a custom message and pass it to [`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host) with `-BackgroundColor` red.

  - `$_.TargetObject` contains the offending path.

To put it all together:

```bash
Copy-Item -Path $sourceFolder -Destination $backupFolder -Recurse -Force 2>&1 | 
  ForEach-Object { 
    Write-Host -BackgroundColor Red "Error: access to $($_.TargetObject) denied and not backed up." 
  }
```

Note:

- The above assumes that *all* errors are access-denied errors; more work is needed to handle different types of errors.

Comment: This has worked.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've seen, `Copy-Item` won't do this.

One option, of course, is to programmatically recurse through the folder structure and copy each item by one at a time, so you can try/catch on individual items. But that's way slower and multiplies the code you need to write and maintain.

Fortunately there's another option. The thing to remember is Powershell is still a **shell**. That means you can also run basic command line utilities included with your platform... in this case the `robocopy` or `xcopy` programs built into Windows.

We still have a problem, though. I don't think either of these tools will do exactly what you want, in that they both have options similar to the `-SilentlyContinue` switch you've already found to be inadequate. However, `robocopy` does have a some logging options you can use in conjunction with `/r:0` that might be enough for you to work with. [The `/V` switch might also work here.](https://superuser.com/a/993070/1304)